# Advice on structuring data with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

Hope it's okay to ask a question like this in here - I'm a little new to backend and am still finding my way.

I am building a kind of language-learning-themed social media program, but I'm a little lost as to how best to structure all the various bits of data. At the moment I am storing two types of objects in their own MongoDB collections: posts, with a nested array of all the replies, and users. At the moment that's working okay, however there's lots of things I'm intending to add down the line, and would quite like to get my data structured in a way where that isn't problematic later.

For instance, one feature I am intending to add is a phrasebook, where users can save messages or words to a personal list, that they can access later or export. Currently I'm planning to create a separate collection for these phrasebooks, with a string that links it to the user's ID, and then an array of phrase. But is that bad practice? Should I be trying to keep my number of collections to a minimum, or is it fine to have lots of different ones?

If anyone has suggestions of where I can read up more on best practice around this too, I'd appreciate that a lot! I've tried to google but haven't had much luck.

Comment: In general, the data that is queried together should stay together. It is not a bad-practice to store the related data in another collection - but, if you can avoid it, do so. What kind of queries are you going to make on this related data, how much data, how often, etc., tells you if you should have a different collection (or within the same collection). Also refer: MongoDB's [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

Comment: Thanks @prasad_ - for this example, I will be calling user data very often through the general flow of the app, but only accessing phrasebooks through a quite specific phrasebook component, so in that case it maybe is okay to have it separate? But thanks a lot for sharing that introduction, I will digest that 

Comment: Do refer MongoDB Data Modeling posts with one-to-many relationship data (on this forum, for example), for more ideas.